# Publish verification results with a version tag in pact-jvm-provider-spring_2.12

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pact

When I want to publish verification results to my pact broker I have to add:

```
pact.verifier.publishResults=true
```

alongside with the provider version:

```
pact.provider.version=0.0.1
```

My question is: How do I specify the provider tag?
I haven't seen an option to do that in pact-jvm-provider-spring or in pact-jvm-provider-junit..

Answer (score 0):

The tag in the broker is on the contract, not the provider, so what you are asking for doesn't make sense.

When a provider fetches a pact, verifies it and publishes the result, any tags associated with the pact will know about the result.